# Typeahead.js - Multiple Datasets using one Remote Source

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, typeahead.js, searchkick

I'm currently using typeahead.js with the searchkick rails gem to search and autocomplete queries.  With the necessary adjustments to my controller I am now searching for records across two models (Artists and Albums):

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def autocomplete
    @results = Artist.search(params[:query], index_name: [Artist.searchkick_index.name, Album.searchkick_index.name], fields: [{ name: :word_start }], limit: 10)

    render json: @results
  end
end
```

---

```
resources :search, only: :index do
  collection do
    get :autocomplete
  end
end
```

Search suggestions for the two are retrieved as expected but I now need to group the two in their own templates. This has led me to looking into using **[Multiple Datasets](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#multiple-datasets)**.

In my js file I'm retrieving results using the `remote` as suggested in this **[post](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/1219)**:

```
remote: { 
  url: "/search/autocomplete?query=%QUERY",
  wildcard: "%QUERY" 
}
```

Unlike what I have, the docs suggest pulling from the model's index action by using the `prefetch` option:

```
prefetch: '../data/nhl.json'
```

Unfortunately configuring my js in this manner gives me nothing. Presumably I'd need an `albums` variable but would it not just be identical to how I have my `artists` variable setup? How would I go about in configuring this based on the JS I have now?

```
$(function() {
  var artists = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace("artist"),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: { 
      url: "/search/autocomplete?query=%QUERY",
      wildcard: "%QUERY" 
    }
  });

  artists.initialize();

  $(".search").typeahead(null, {
    displayKey: "name",
    source: artists.ttAdapter(),
    templates: { 
      header: "<h3>Artists</h3>",
      suggestion: function(data) {
        return "<a href=" + data.url + ">"+ data.name +"</a>";
      }
    },
    {
     // Albums would go here
    }
  });
});
```

**Returned JSON**

```
/* artists.json */

{
id: 1,
name: "50 Cent",
avatar: ...,
url: "/artists/1"
}

/* albums.json */

{
id: 1,
name: "Get Rich or Die Tryin'",
artwork: ...,
genre: "Hip-Hop/Rap",
release_date: ...,
url: "/albums/1"
}
```

Comment: Can include example of returned data from each "artists", "albums" `json` ? One approach could be to filter results displayed at `templates` using a property of returned data

Comment: Updated my answer. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes. If `url` property of returned objects begins with `"/artists"` , `"/albums"` , respectively, could filter `template` displayed using those properties

Comment: Could you give an example? Ideally I could include the object's class in my serializer so it could read something like `data.class => "artist"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `suggestion` property of `templates` to filter displayed results using `url` of returned `data` , `RegExp.prototype.test()`

```
$(".search").typeahead(null, {
    displayKey: "name",
    source: artists.ttAdapter(),
    templates: { 
      // header: "<h3>Artists</h3>",
      suggestion: function(data) {
        var temp;
        if (/^\/albums/.test(data.url)) {
           // albums template
           // temp = "albums template"
        } else {
           // temp = "artists template"
        }
        return temp;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Do you take any sort've performance blow when using regex for each query lookup?

Comment: @CarlEdwards Should not affect performance. Could alternatively use `String.prototype.slice()` , or `String.prototype.match()`

Comment: Okay thanks. Also how would you go about in conditionally setting the `header` being that it's outside the `suggestion` function scope and doesn't have access to the `data` object?

Comment: @CarlEdwards Could initially load header `h3` as empty element , perhaps provide a unique `className` , then within `suggestion` , once type of `data` is determined , append appropriate `html` to `h3` . Alternatively, create `h3` element as first element of `temp`